# Ethernet won't work with dual boot win7, win7 also happens to be broken. RTL8111/8168/8411

Tags: networking, dual-boot

My pc has been going haywire lately and after some playing around it seems the issue is the win7 OS. Booting to win7 is very volatile, the whole computer will just shut down. No bsod or any warning. I can get into my Ubuntu partition and that seems to work. Booting from win7 or attempting that is, will cause the whole machine to have a hard time booting at all, but after some time Ubuntu can be booted safely. Unfortunate for me, Internet access seems to not be there.

My mobo is connected via Ethernet but cant connect to the Internet. I've just finished getting most if not all of my important data from the Windows partition into the Ubuntu side and would love to just get internet access working. If I have to wipe the win7 partition that's fine. Ideally I want to still have Windows to run games and unity editor, lookin k just have Windows as a smal partition. I have Ubuntu 16.04.

Any help would be appreciated, I really don't think I can access win7 partition. Just crashes, so any solutions involving me logging into win7 likely are just not going to be workable.

I can post pics of anything y'all need me to run. Thanks for any help.

Here's the current list of images for output. If you need any info, ask away, if there are multiple commands show me all of them to condense number of images. Thanks again.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` to your question?

Comment: Sorry it took a while. I'm on mobile and ended up having to get the app to post the image. Typing all of this on mobile would have been difficult. https://i.imgur.com/abv4l5o.jpg

Comment: Yes I know how difficult things are on mobile. Can you simply update your question with the name of your RTL model number? I can't read it in your screen picture. I don't use the same model number but hopefully others with that model can share a solution.

Comment: Sounds like the crashing could be caused by faulty RAM. Can you please run Prime 95 in blend mode for ~4ish hours and report if it gives any errors?

Comment: @AndroidDev 4 hour RAM test when boot takes 14 seconds? If it happened on random boot that makes sense but from OP it appears to happen every boot.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - Which is why it might be a bad RAM controller.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have two separate problems.

## Problem #1

Windows not booting. Boot to the Windows install CD/DVD and go to troubleshooting and repair startup problems. Follow the steps and see if it'll repair the Windows problem.

## Problem #2

The r8169 driver that your ethernet card is using is buggy. You need to use a different driver, the `r8168-dkms` driver. Boot Ubuntu. Start Synaptic. Click the RELOAD icon. Then click the SEARCH icon, and type in `r8168-dkms`. In the results pane, mark it for install. Click the APPLY icon. Reboot.